# Avoid removing all subsequent div elements when using parent() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have tried using closest() and parent() jquery methods but both seem to delete all of the divs following the one I am trying to remove . I do not wish to assign an ID to each new div as they are dynamically generated

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.add_row', function() {
    alert("add new row method called");
    $(".student_mounting").last().append('<div  class="student_mounting">' +
      '<button  class="add_row" src="../images/add-resource.png">Add</button>' +
      '<button  class="remove_row" src="../images/exit.png">Remove</button>' +
      '</div>');
  });


  $(document).on('click', '.remove_row', function() {
    $(this).closest().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.student_mounting {
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 265px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 120px;
  background-color: #F4EBBC;
  z-index: 4;
  border: 2px solid #6B4235;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="student_mounting">
  <button class="add_row" src="../images/add-resource.png">Add</button>
  <button class="remove_row" src="../images/exit.png">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I add another parent div having id 'studentParent' and we add all the dynamically created div inside this parent div. So that it will work when we remove the div using parent() function.

When you execute this code you can identify that which div is removed when we press the remove button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
 {      

   $(document).on('click' ,'.add_row', function() 
   {
    alert("add new row method called");
    var value=$("#HidVal").val();
    value++;
    $("#HidVal").val(value);
     $("#studentParent" ).last().append('<div  class="student_mounting">'+
      '<button  class="add_row" src="../images/add-resource.png">Add '+value+'</button>'+
      '<button  class="remove_row" src="../images/exit.png">Remove</button>'+
     '</div>');   
  });


  $(document).on('click' ,'.remove_row', function()
  {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.student_mounting {

position:relative;
top:12px;
height:120px;
width:265px;
border-radius:6px;
margin-top:120px;
background-color:#F4EBBC;
z-index:4;
border: 2px solid #6B4235;
border-radius: 5px;
color: black;
} 
</style>
<div id="studentParent"> 
<input type="hidden" id="HidVal" value="1">
<div class="student_mounting">
  <button  class="add_row" src="../images/add-resource.png">Add 1</button>
  <button  class="remove_row" src="../images/exit.png">Remove</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks but both of these still remove any divs after the selected one is closed. Is there any way to remove a newly created div without removing all subsequently created divs?

Comment: Currently all the subsequent divs are not deleted. In this case the div where the currently clicked remove button in located is removed. Do you want to remove the lastly added div regardless of which div's remove button is clicked?

Comment: I tried it on JS fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/e6915u2r/   and if I add say two new boxes to create three in total and then delete the middle one the last one is also deleted. I am wondering if it is because it is binding the event to the div in the DOM and not to the current Div?

Comment: I have edited my code in my answer so that you can identify which div is removed when you press on remove button. In this code snippet only the div where the remove button is residing is removed.

Comment: Is this is your expected output?

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for excellent advice thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Your positive feedback is a great inspiration for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your expected output is to delete the container where you click on remove, check below snippet.

Everything perfect in your code except you missed to mention what you want to find through `closest()` function. So here I passed closest div's class as parameter. Hope it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.add_row', function() {
    alert("add new row method called");
    $(".student_mounting").last().append('<div  class="student_mounting">' +
      '<button  class="add_row" src="../images/add-resource.png">Add</button>' +
      '<button  class="remove_row" src="../images/exit.png">Remove</button>' +
      '</div>');
  });


  $(document).on('click', '.remove_row', function() {
    $(this).closest('.student_mounting').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.student_mounting {
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 265px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 120px;
  background-color: #F4EBBC;
  z-index: 4;
  border: 2px solid #6B4235;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="student_mounting">
  <button class="add_row" src="../images/add-resource.png">Add</button>
  <button class="remove_row" src="../images/exit.png">Remove</button>
</div>
```